# Python Altair Bar Plots - How to change the number of bars?

Tags: python, visualization, altair

I'm a newbie to Altair, and I would like to change the number of bars being plotted in a bar plot. I have done some research online, but couldn't find anything helpful. Here is my code:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Generate a random np array of size 1000, and our goal is to plot its distribution.
my_numbers = np.random.normal(size = 1000)
my_numbers_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Integers': my_numbers})

alt.Chart(my_numbers_df).mark_bar(size = 10).encode(
    alt.X("Integers", 
          bin = True,
          scale = alt.Scale(domain=(-5, 5))
    ),
    y = 'count()',
)
```

The plot right now looks something like this
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase the number of bins by passing an `alt.Bin()` object and specifying the `maxbins`

```py
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Generate a random np array of size 1000, and our goal is to plot its distribution.
my_numbers = np.random.normal(size = 1000)
my_numbers_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Integers': my_numbers})

alt.Chart(my_numbers_df).mark_bar(size = 10).encode(
    alt.X("Integers", 
          bin = alt.Bin(maxbins=25),
          scale = alt.Scale(domain=(-5, 5))
    ),
    y = 'count()',

)
```

[image: histogram with 25 bins]